# Use Tkinter to Open file, run script and export file

Tags: python, excel, class, button, tkinter

I would like to create a pyton script that takes an excel file (provided by the user), run a script, and save this excel file (with a file name provided by the user). 
I would like to implement some buttons using Tkinter to enable non-programmers to easily use my algorithm.

I tried to create a ''load data'' and ''display data'' button (I took a code online) that both work.

However I didn't manage to run the script on the database imported (as I don't know how to access it)

I didnt manage to create a button that enables the user to choose the name of the file they want to save it to.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import pandas as pd

import csv

# --- classes ---

class MyWindow:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent = parent

        self.filename = None
        self.df = None

        self.text = tk.Text(self.parent)
        self.text.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='LOAD DATA', command=self.load)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='DISPLAY DATA', command=self.display)
        self.button.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='DISPLAY DATA', command=self.display)
        self.button.pack()

    def load(self):

        name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('CSV', '*.csv',), ('Excel', ('*.xls', '*.xslm', '*.xlsx'))])

        if name:
            if name.endswith('.csv'):
                self.df = pd.read_csv(name)
            else:
                self.df = pd.read_excel(name)

            self.filename = name

             display directly
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')



    def display(self):
        # ask for file if not loaded yet
        if self.df is None:
            self.load_file()

        # display if loaded
        if self.df is not None:
            self.text.insert('end', self.filename + '\n')
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')

    #def script_python(self):
       # self.df=self.df.iloc[:, :-1]
       #this is not my original script


    #def file_save(self):
    #    savefile = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
         #                               ("All files", "*.*") ))



# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = MyWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

My python script that do analysis on the excel file works, so I just put a very simple python script to make your life easier.

Thank you 
I'm new at Tkinter and not used to classes and dictionaries. thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like you can simply access the imported database from `self.df`

Comment: So in my function I should just put : def script_python(self.df) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code, adding a button to run your script and a button to save the data (I've tried to keep the rest as close to your original code as possible):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import pandas as pd

import csv

# --- classes ---

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent = parent

        self.filename = None
        self.df = None

        self.text = tk.Text(self.parent)
        self.text.pack()

        # load data button
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='LOAD DATA', command=self.load)
        self.load_button.pack()

        # display data button
        self.display_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='DISPLAY DATA', command=self.display)
        self.display_button.pack()

        # run script button
        self.script_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='RUN SCRIPT', command=self.script_python)
        self.script_button.pack()

        # save data button
        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='SAVE DATA', command=self.file_save)
        self.save_button.pack()

    def load(self):
        name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('CSV', '*.csv',), ('Excel', ('*.xls', '*.xslm', '*.xlsx'))])

        if name:
            if name.endswith('.csv'):
                self.df = pd.read_csv(name)
            else:
                self.df = pd.read_excel(name)

            self.filename = name

            # display directly
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')

    def display(self):
        # ask for file if not loaded yet
        if self.df is None:
            self.load_file()

        # display if loaded
        if self.df is not None:
            self.text.insert('end', self.filename + '\n')
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')

    def script_python(self):
        # replace this with the real thing
        self.df = self.df.iloc[:, :-1]

    def file_save(self):
        fname = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
                                        ("All files", "*.*")))
        # note: this will fail unless user ends the fname with ".xlsx"
        self.df.to_excel(fname)


# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = MyWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I spent hours looking for a solution and your answer helped. Great job !