# Python - run a Pandas script with a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to set up a GUI with tkinter, I used this post -
[Use Tkinter to Open file, run script and export file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523959/use-tkinter-to-open-file-run-script-and-export-file) as a reference and a great tutorial on youtube -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8-snVfekto&t=2374s.

I want to be able to browse for a file, execute a pandas script that i have (for this example i only wrote something simple just to check if it works) and then save it.
i'm having some issues with the script_python function. I get a name "df" is not defined error.
(I called global df because i had a "local variable 'df' referenced before assignment" error and that what solved it)
It should be a straight forward solution but somehow i can't wrap my head around it.
Thanks a lot!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import pandas as pd




HEIGHT=400 
WIDTH=500


def load():
    name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('CSV', '*.csv',), ('Excel', ('*.xls', '*.xslm', '*.xlsx'))])
    if name.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(name)
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(name)
    return df


            
def script_python():
    global df
    df = df.drop(columns=['x','y'])
    

def file_save():
    fname = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files", "*.*")))
    df.to_excel(fname)

root= tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='pic.png')
background_label =tk.Label(root,image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1,relheight=1)

frame= tk.Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1,relwidth=0.5,relheight=0.1, anchor= 'n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text= 'Browse file', font=40, command=load) 
button.place(relx=0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1,anchor='n')

lower_frame= tk.Frame(root,bg='#80c1ff',bd=5)
lower_frame.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='s')

lower_button = tk.Button(lower_frame, text= 'Execute script', font=10,command=script_python) 
lower_button.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1,anchor='s')

save_button=tk.Button(root, text= 'Save', font=40,command=file_save) 
save_button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

your `file_save()` function does not declares `df` as `global` so it does not "know" the global `df`.

Comment: your `load` returns local variable df. I am not sure who uses this return value. Maybe you meant this df to be global too?

Comment: Thanks for the help Lior. I want the df loaded with `load()` to run with `script_python()`...